# Using Entity Framework Code First to connect to Legacy Oracle Database with devart dotconnect

Tags: c#, oracle10g, ef-code-first, entity-framework-ctp5, dotconnect

**ERROR:  The Type clob is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only PrimitiveTypes can be used without qualification.**

I have been trying out to use EF 4.1 (code first) with MVC 3, against a legacy Oracle 10g database, using devart dotconnect.  The legacy database **cannot** be changed.  I'm trying to read the data in it out to a webpage.

(Devart.Data.Oracle Version: 5.70.140.0)

I've had a few errors to overcome along the way, but came to this one:

> error 0040: The Type clob is not qualified with a namespace or alias.
>   Only PrimitiveTypes can be used without qualification.

This is my code:

Web.config connection info:

```
<add name="OdeToTrainingCoursesDB"
              connectionString="User Id=test;Password=test;Server=##.#.#.#;
                      Home=OraClient10g;Direct=True; 
                      Sid=dbTest;Persist Security Info=True"
              providerName="Devart.Data.Oracle" />



namespace AllInOne
{
    public class OdeToTrainingCoursesDB : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<VENUES> VENUES { get; set; }
    }
}



using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AllInOne.Models
{
    public class VENUES
    {
        [Key]
        public int VENUE_ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Extra info, this is the first table (of many) that I'm trying to read from.

```
CREATE TABLE VENUES
(
  VENUE_ID    NUMBER(10)                        NOT NULL,
  VENUE_TYP   VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  BASE_ORG    NUMBER(10)                        NOT NULL,
  COUNTY      VARCHAR2(35 BYTE)
)
```

And the MVC Controller throws this

> Local = '(model).Local' threw an exception of type
>   'System.Data.MetadataException'

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AllInOne.Controllers
{
    public class VenueController : Controller
    {
        readonly OdeToTrainingCoursesDB _db = new OdeToTrainingCoursesDB();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = _db.VENUES;

            return View(model);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have replied to you [at our forum](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21488).

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks for the fast and comprehensive response.